# Multiple items in Java - reusability and maintainability

Tags: java, android, arrays, list, object

What is the best way/practice when dealing with multiple items in Java/Android in terms of **maintainability** and **reusability** and why? For example, when coding functionality for:

- a shopping application. Each and every shopping cart will consist of one or more pre-existing items (which user has added there from the shop).
- a fitness application. Each and every workout will consist of one or more pre-existing exercises (which user has added there from the list).

Suppose you want to easily be able to extend this collection of items available for the user to choose from every now and then. Would it then be best to store the shopping items or exercises as instances of an object and then create a list of those objects for individual shopping or workout session? Or rather store it as pure text inside a big array? Or anything else? Why?

Answer (score 2):

You should use an `ArrayList<E>`, that can store elements of the user-defined classes too.

Because while declaring an `ArrayList`, you don't have to specify the number of the element it would store.

When you want to add any element in that you can simply use a `add()` method. And this will increase the size of reapective `ArrayList` automatically. So, you can easily extend your `ArrayList`.

Answer (score 1):

You should use LinkedList<> if you update your collection frequently and you are not access a lot to the collection in a specific place(Like indexes: 15,27..).

ArrayList<> you will use when you less update your collection and you're more frequently access to the collections.

Answer (score 1):

Both guys above provide a valid solution, but you should use the generic `List<T>` interface, not `LinkedList<T>` or `ArrayList<T>` specifically.
If your requirements change later on, keeping things generic is nice for reusability and maintenance.

i.E.

```
List<MyItem> items = new ArrayList<>();
```

or

```
List<MyItem> items = new LinkedList<>();
```